# Will the command `script /dev/null` stop or affect the running applications and server?

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal, gnu-screen

I can login to the server terminal with username and password. But I can't run the `screen` command. It says **Must be connected to a terminal** while I ran this `screen -R newNodeServer`.

I found an answer at [Ask Ubuntu: What does the script /dev/null do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306047/what-does-the-script-dev-null-do), but if I run the command `script /dev/null` according to that answer, will the running server, websites, and applications be affected?

I am going to run some `artisan` commands for Laravel in screens. Such as `php artisan queue` and `php artisan websockets:serve`

Comment: I myself would be asking the more obvious question _Why, if I am logged in to a terminal, is the computer saying that I am not connected to a terminal?_.

Comment: @JdeBP, That's I already running with the terminal

Comment: I cannot make any sense of that sentence.

Comment: @JdeBP because older versions of `screen` will try to open the current terminal _via its path_, and that may not work on Linux: it's the same problem as with `su other_user -c 'cat /dev/stdout'` or `su other_user -c 'cat /dev/tty'`, etc.

Comment: Maybe check the answer to that same Q on _this_ site: [What does 'script /dev/null' do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511267/what-does-script-dev-null-do)

Comment: And no, running `script /dev/null` will not affect your websites, applications or finances; it just creates another pseudo-tty, just like `screen` itself does.

Comment: Don't tell me.  Tell the person with the problem.  I'm just explaining what the better question to ask is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess here is:

1. @testteam is trying to run `screen` command and getting `screen` complaining about not being able to open terminal.
2. In the [answer linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306047/what-does-the-script-dev-null-do), solution mentioned is to use `script /dev/null` and that should resolve the issue.
3. @testteam is wondering if that's going to affect any servers running on the machine (probably in the `screen` session).

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/255531/86410) has very good explanation what `script` command is going to do and why `screen` is complaining:

> Why this works is invoking `script` has a side effect of creating a pseudo-terminal for you at `/dev/pts/X`. This way you don't have to do it yourself, and `screen` won't have permission issues - if you `su` from user A to user B, by directly invoking screen you try to grab possession of user A's pseudo-terminal. This won't succeed unless you're root.

So the fact that `script` solves the issue with `screen` is basically side effect. I'm guessing that you want to run some node.js app in the `screen` session. The fact that you created `pts` device and used `script` for that **should not** affect servers or (web)apps running inside screen session.

Comment: I am going to use the screen for artisan commands. So see the updated question, please

Comment: And what's about the last part of the linked answer(https://serverfault.com/a/255531/86410) "This won't succeed unless you're root. That's why you see the error message."?

Comment: _Newer version_ of  `screen` are perfectly able to "grab posession" of the terminal without being root. I don't think that the answers you link to do such a great job explaining why older versions of `screen` aren't able to do it.