# How to use host PTY in container?

Tags: tty, init, namespace, container, getty

I'm learning about container technologies of Linux and wrote a minimal container implementation on my own. I'm currently confused about consoles / terminals for container processes, as I'm "reusing" the controlling terminal as `/dev/console` (instead of `c 5 1`) in the container.

I determine the current terminal from `/proc/self/fd/0` and `/proc/self/fd/2`, read its device node (major and minor), and `mknod(2)` using the discovered device nodes to create `/dev/console` node in the container.

This appears fine when running a regular application like `/bin/sh` as PID 1 (in PID namespace), but not when through an init system (I used BusyBox for this).

Here's my `/etc/inittab` for the BusyBox rootfs:

```
::sysinit:/bin/true
::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

However, the shell spawned by init always complains `can't access tty; job control turned off`. I also tried using the same host TTY node for `/dev/tty` (instead of `c 5 0`) but this problem still persists.

[image]

I looked into the source code of `systemd-nspawn` and found that it [creates a "forwarded pty"](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/1f667d8a7cff4355cd23ebebeb4d7179e3498eb8/src/nspawn/nspawn.c#L4648), where the container runs on a new PTY that's "forwarded" to the host side. The code is too complex for my educational project so it's not viable for me.

How can I use the host terminal for the container?

---

Details: My container program `clone(2)` only one child with flags = `CLONE_NEWGROUP | CLONE_NEWNET | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWIPC | CLONE_NEWUTS | SIGCHLD`, and the child sets up capabilities (blacklisting) and seccomp (whitelisting, syscall list taken from [Docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json)), before `pivot_root(2)` to the container rootfs and `execve(2)` into the target application.

I'm currently experimenting on Linux 5.3 (Ubuntu 18.04 HWE), but I don't expect this to be different on any recent Linux versions.

Comment: Instead of `::respawn:-/bin/sh`, use `::respawn:/bin/cttyhack /bin/sh`. This is a well known problem, well explained in the `//config` comments from the cttyhack [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brgl/busybox/master/shell/cttyhack.c)

Comment: running `script /dev/null` (which will create a pseudo-tty owned by you) [also works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511275/308316) in cases like this.